# Find all intervals such that $\sin(2\pi t)$ and $\cos(2\pi t)$ are orthogonal.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to find all intervals $[a,b]$ on which the functions $\sin(2\pi t)$ and $\cos(2pi t)$ are orthogonal.

$$\int_a^b \sin(2\pi t)\cdot \cos(2\pi t) dt = \frac{\cos(4\pi b) - cos(4\pi a)}{8\pi} = 0$$

$$\iff \cos(4\pi b + 2\pi k) = cos(4\pi a + 2\pi l), k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$$

I don't know how to solve this for $a$ and $b$, can anybody help me with that please?

Comment: $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are periodic (with period $2\pi$), so you can assume $a\equiv b \ \text{mod}\ 2\pi$ (change of variables $t\to t+2\pi$ in your integral).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\cos(4\pi a)-\cos(4\pi b)}{8\pi}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(4\pi a)-\cos(4\pi b)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\cos(4\pi b)=-\cos(4\pi a)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(4\pi b)=\cos(4\pi a)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$4\pi b=4\pi a+2\pi n_1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space 4\pi b=2\pi n_1-4\pi a\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$b=a+\frac{n_1}{2}\space\space\vee\space\space b=\frac{n_2}{2}-a$$

With $n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{Z}$

---

So you can set:

$$b=\pm a+\frac{n}{2}\space,n\in\mathbb{Z}$$